# How to update DB record using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to update a record of a database.

**Here is the code:**

On my index page.

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

<h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
<div class="main">
    <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
</div>
<p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>
<p><a href="news/delete/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">Delete article</a></p>
<p><a href="news/update/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">Update article</a></p>
```

On my update.php page.

```
<h2>Update a news item</h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('news/update') ?>

<label for="title">Title</label>
<input type="input" name="title" /><br />

<label for="text">Text</label>
<textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update news item" />

</form>
```

On my news.php page.

```
    public function update($slug)
{

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->news_model->update_news($slug);
    redirect ('news', 'refresh');
}
```

On my news_model.php page.

```
    public function update_news($slug)
{

$this->load->helper('url');

$data = array(
               'title' => $title,
               'slug' => $slug,
               'text' => $this->input->post('text')
            );

$this->db->where('title', $slug);
$this->db->update('news', $data); 

}
```

My routing page.

```
$route['news/update/(:any)'] = 'news/update/$1';    
$route['news/delete/(:any)'] = 'news/delete/$1';
$route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

I'm trying to update the record the user clicks on.

However, instead of sending the slug to the update page, which has the form on to update the record, the code runs all the way through and updates the record to "0" values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After a few comments, I can now see your problem. This is how I would fix it;

Your index file seems fine. It's your update function, within your controller where the problem lies. You're expecting to see the update form, but you're not actually loading the view;

Try replace the function, with this one;

```
public function update($slug)
{
    if (!$this->input->post('submit'))
    {
      // The form was NOT posted
      // So we load the view
      $data['selected_article'] = $this->news_model->get_by_slug($slug);
      $this->load->view('update', $data);
    }
    else
    {
      // The form was submitted
      $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'slug' => $this->input->post('slug'),
        'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
      );

      $this->news_model->update_news($slug, $data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: the $slug is getting passed from the view page which is the id of the article that is being clicked. i will edit the code so you can see it in context. I want to pass the $slug (id) to the update page were the form is

Comment: You are passing the slug (or ID) to the form, but you're not passing it from the form, to the controller. When you hit "Update news item" the form is going to the "news" controller, to the "update" function. Whereas you want to to also bring through the ID, for the slug.

Comment: When i click the update record, the page is not found and the values of the record is  set to 0. For some reason i cant navigate to the update form page?

Comment: Where do you load your view? $this->load->view() ?

Comment: Exactly. when i click on the Update Article on the index page, nothing happens apart from the values of that specific record change to 0. Its totally missing out the update page.

Comment: Looking at your code, you will never see the update form.

When you click "update article", you go off to the update function, which goes to the model and returns. You never actually load a view.

I will update my answer, with some fixed code.

Comment: The update page is now showing, however when i type in the boxes and click update, the page is not found

Comment: Change your form_open, to this; <?php echo form_open('news/update/' . $this->uri->segment(3)) ?>

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:

```
$data = array(
           'title' => $title,
           'slug' => $slug,
           'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );
```

be this:

```
$data = array(
           'title' => $this->input->post('title'), //-->post variable
           'slug' => $slug,
           'text' => $this->input->post('text')
        );
```

Also, are you sure that the `$title` variable is exactly the same as `$slug`?
If `$title`= 'My title', and `$slug`= 'my-title', they won't match and this won't run as expected:

```
$this->db->where('title', $slug);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a  function in my form model file, there I just want to update some of the records that previously have been uploaded in a db:

```
public function update_records($id_aUsar){
    $data = array(
        'asunto'  =>  $this->input->post('tema'),
        'remite'  =>  $this->input->post('emite'),
        'mensaje' =>  $this->input->post('content'),
        'dirigido' => $this->input->post('paraGrupo'),
        'fechaEnvio'=> $this->input->post('fechaEnvio'),
        'observaciones' => $this->input->post('notas')
    );

    $this->db->where('id_masivos', $id_aUsar);
    $this->db->set('fecha', 'NOW()', FALSE);
    $this->db->update('masivos_texto', $data); 
}
```

where `$id_aUsar` is the primary key id of the row I want to update, I get the id from my session value, in order to keep the same session (my primary key id_masivos is type AUTOINCREMENT), the array entries are the only data to be updated after the user updates some of the fields (all of then including), but only those I show in the function are essential to the records update. Then in my controller I access my model added fuction like this:

```
$this->forma_model->update_records($id_tarea);
```

where `$id_tarea` is the current session id for that user in that session, that´s how I update records without losing the primary key id.